# What is wrong with my baseUrl when I try to set it?

Tags: asp.net, requirejs

(Warning: requirejs newbie) I'm trying to set my baseUrl for require.config but I'm getting an error on a very very simple setup. I've tried many different combos with slashes but no luck.

[image]

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Requirejs way</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1><span id="foo">Hello World</span></h1>
    <input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" />

    <script data-main="common" src="Scripts/require.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        require(['common'], function () {
            //Load up this page's script, once the 'common' script has loaded
            require(['home']);
        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**common.js**

```
/*
The first JS file to be loaded. Takes care of setting up all the required paths.
*/

// Configure RequireJS
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: "Scripts",
    paths: {
        jquery: [

            //If the CDN fails, load it from the following
            'jquery-3.1.1'
        ]
    }
});

require(['home'], function (Methods) {
    Methods.doSomething();
})
```

**home.js**

```
define(['jquery'], function ($) {
    $('#Button1').on("click", function () {
        $('#foo').text('[changed by jQuery]');
    });

    var Methods = {
        doSomething: function () {
            alert('i just did something');
        }
    };

    return Methods;
});
```

Resource for code [Go](https://youtu.be/eRqsZqLyYaU)

Comment: The error you get is the type of error normally raised when there is a SyntaxError in the code of a module. If you are not getting any network errors, then it is unlikely the problem is purely with `baseUrl`.

Comment: If I move Scripts out of baseUrl and leave it blank, then change below path to 'Scripts/jquery-3.1.1' it works.

Comment: but I guess I'm still not understanding how I'd use the baseUrl in this case